# Наскільки доцільним є питання "поширені помилки української мови" на головному сайті?

Tags: discussion

В українській мові, як і в будь-якій мові, є велика кількість поширених помилок. Це можуть бути помилки, пов'язані з наголосом (багато російськомовних українців говорять `укра́инский`, а не `украи́нский`), кальки з російської (`на протязі`, а не `протягом`), правила правопису іншомовних слів (`барокко`, а не `бароко`).

Є досить велика кількість розрізнених статей (наприклад, [тут](http://www.uamodna.com/articles/-8-poshyrenyh-pomylok-v-ukrayinsjkiy-movi/) і [тут](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-38895377)), є [сторінка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA) в Вікіпедії. Створювати питання для кожного випадку вважає не найкращим рішенням, а питання в стилі "поширені помилки української мови" може вважатись занадто широким.

Якщо подивитись на інші Q&A сайти, зокрема, StackOverflow, то можна знайти багато подібних питань:

1. [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)
2. [What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon)

Не дивлячись та те, що вони не є типовими питаннями, проте мають важливе значення і велику кількість посилань, відповідей та коментарів.

Як ви вважаєте?

Comment: I updated [my answer](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/60/4).

Comment: +1 за посилання!

Answer (score 4):

Ага, і до кожного з ваших прикладів приліплений дісклеймер: "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please **do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.** This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed."

Іншими словами такі питання більше не вважаються доцільними і корисними і будуть закриватися як не відповідні до правил. І що не можна посилатися на існування подібних питаннь щоб обґрунтувати нові подібного типу.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain it logically, but I have nothing against this idea — at least, if every item is argued by some references.

Important addition: How do I actually imagine it — a question with a **single wiki-answer** of fixed format (e.g. alphabetically-ordered bulleted-list of items with shortly-titled sources at the end of each item in parentheses; not a bunch of free-form answers).

Comment: Буде вкрай важко слідкувати за правильністю таких порад. Залишмо це все wiki: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA#cite_ref-dzvonadzvonu_1-0
Тим паче у нас в джерелах є це посилання

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, з одного боку — можна спробувати. А якщо будуть порушувати — видалити (наявність лише однієї вікі-відповіді, мабуть, можна регламентувати, створивши її самим і закривши після цього питання (чи в такому випадку і редагувати вікі-відповідь стане неможливо?); необхідність посилань і збереження формату можна написати великими напівжирними в самому питанні та зверху/знизу відповіді). З іншого боку — я абсолютно не наполягаю.

Comment: я поясню, чому в мене різна позиція щодо цього питання й питання про корисні джерела. На українській вікі вже є список, який можуть редагувати користувачі. Хай краще там редагують, доповнюють, поліпшують. У цього сайту своє завдання: відповідати на конкретні питання. Списку джерел, які можна вільно редагувати я не знаю - тому можемо його й тут підтримувати. І підтримувати його буде значно легше

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, я поясню, чому я сприймаю ідею списку помилок на основному сайті легше, ніж ідею списку посилань на основному сайті — бо на мою думку список помилок якраз значно легше підтримувати. Помилки не старіють (хіба що раз на 50 років), помилки будуть корисними при простій лінійно-алфавітній структурі (посилання — ні), додання помилок об'єктивніше (є джерело — додавай, нема джерела — не додавай; одне джерело каже, що то помилка, інше, що ні, — додай з позначкою «можливо»+обидва джерела). Але я не наполягаю на доданні помилок, я ставлюся **нейтрально** (*не формат — так не формат*).